# Blue Box with White Question Mark

Tags: macos, safari, macbook-pro

On certain websites (minecraftforum.net) most images appear as a blue box with a white question mark in it on safari. On my school forums (private to the school only, so can't link) normal images work fine, but an animated GIF generates the same blue box. The images do not load in chrome or firefox. Anyone know why?

I have safari 6.1, I'm on a MacBook, and I'm running osx 10.7.5

Comment: Does this happen all the time, or only on school premises? It could be a proxy problem

Comment: This occurs mostly on either minecraftforum.net and my school forum. On the school forum, normal pictures work, just not animated gifs.

Comment: I meant does it happen when you are in a different physical location (say, at home, or in a coffee shop). also, have you tried right clicking on the blue box, and getting the link to the picture, and going directly to it? does that work?

Comment: Ummm, I'm a homeschooler, this is an online school. I don't really have the option to try this anywhere else. If I can I'll try.

Comment: @RossMcKinley When I click the blue boxes, it does nothing. I'll ask and see if others can see them.

Comment: Ok, it "sounds" like it's a proxy problem. It may be the case that your ISP (internet service provider) is blocking the images based on some sort of censorship rules, or perhaps it thinks you're using a mobile device to access the internet, and believes that you don't want to receive "large" images such as .gifs

Comment: Ok, one thing to add. One person's gifs are working. Now my guess is that there is some sort of link problem with the people that are posting bad gifs. There or only a couple of people doing the blue boxes, so that may be it.

Answer (score 1):

When you access the school's forums, are you on a VPN? If so they may be filtering larger files, as suggested in a comment.

[This](http://rocketdock.com/images/screenshots/Apple-GIF.gif) animated .gif file works fine for me in Safari. Make sure its not working for you before we go looking for local causes to your problem, rather than forum or gateway problems you and others have alluded to.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem on the webserver, not something you can fix in Safari itself, the web admin has to fix it.

One specific jpg image on my website was showing as a blue box with white question mark.

Only in Safari - Chrome and Firefox were displaying the jpg file correctly.

I looked on the webserver, noticed that this particular file was very large in comparison to the others.

(In this case it was 400K in size where the others were around 30K in size).

My solution was to re-size the file to a "normal" size, there are lots of ways to do this, I used https://imageoptim.com/mac

Answer (score -1):

Try resetting the cache on Safari (Safari > Reset Safari > Check the "Remove all website data" box) and try again. It's possible that Safari is not refreshing the cache, so try that.

Comment: Tried, didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to install [Onyx](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx) for 10.7 and do some deep cache cleaning. You might also want to make sure your Mac has the latest [Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/), too

Comment: Why would Flash affect display of images?